# How do I setup an Ookla server for speed test?

Tags: ubuntu, https

I'm trying to setup an Ookla server for speed test. My OS is Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) and I installed the script, also set it up to start after reboot, but I don't know how to set it up to work with HTTPS. The [test page](https://www.ookla.com/host-tester) says my server passed on `netgauge`, `websocket` and `crossdomain` but failed on `https`. I would also like to know how I use my server for speed testing before I upload it to Ookla? I would like to know what is the speed and how it performs. I didn't find much documentation on Ookla's website, for example I didn't find how to setup HTTPS. If I get a certificate from Let's encrypt, how do I install and use my certificate?

For installing the server, I followed the links on https://www.speedtest.net/speedtest-servers.

Comment: To get, install and renew letsencrypt certificates have a look here:  https://certbot.eff.org

Comment: @digijay Yes, but I didn't install any web server on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/234578568 says

> Please note that the automatic Let's Encrypt certificate provisioning will not begin until after your server has been submitted and either approved or accepted for use. The HTTPS test on the Server Tester can be ignored during the initial submission period.

I believe your other questions would also best be answered by Ookla support.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ookla's support sent me this link:

https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001087752-How-do-I-enable-HTTPS-TLS-support